# Python unittest, how to display TestCase's methods' docstring in report?

Tags: python, python-unittest

The question title is self-explaining.
Is there a way for

```
class Foo(TestCase):
  def test_bar(self):
    """
    a docstring
    """
```

to make the `UnitTest` report display the whole docstring ?

I've read that the first line of the docstring would be printed (so writing

```
""" a docstring """
```

without line breaks works)

I've read the question : [How to stop Python unittest from printing test docstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962772/how-to-stop-python-unittest-from-printing-test-docstring)

However, it's about removing the docstring, and I don't know how to override the `shortDescription()` to show the full docstring.

Comment: Don't use docstrings in test methods, use self explanatory method names

Comment: I do use self explanatory method names, but I can't describe in a detailed way how a function is expected to behave in a function name. And since my unit tests are growing, I don't want neither to go in the test file to read this description... So if I can make it displayed in the report (at least if the test fails), it would be really great.

Comment: The solution is right in that answer, return `self._testMethodDoc`.

Comment: Since this attribute is not documented and has an underscore, is it safe and durable to use it ?

Comment: I'm sure it won't be renamed/removed soon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*I have not tried this*)

In the [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12962854/1587329) to the [SO-linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962772/how-to-stop-python-unittest-from-printing-test-docstring), it says

> the responsible method is `TestCase.shortDescription()`, which you can
>   override in your testcases.

The [source of shortDescription](https://pythonhosted.org/gchecky/unittest-pysrc.html) is as follows:

```
doc = self._testMethodDoc 
return doc and doc.split("\n")[0].strip() or None
```

So you might be able to modify the second line to

```
return doc
```

yielding

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    #  ....
    def shortDescription(self):
        doc = self._testMethodDoc 
        return doc
```

If you object to using the undocumented `self._testMethodDoc`, it is a direct copy of `testMethod.__doc__`, which is created in `TestCase.__init__()` via

```
testMethod = getattr(self, methodName)
```

There are very few variables for a `TestCase`. The chance of them being renamed is small, but you might ask the author (from the source, as well):

```
 47  __author__ = "Steve Purcell" 
 48  __email__ = "stephen_purcell at yahoo dot com"
```